# Php two rows in one variable

Tags: php, variables, row

Hello i have two rows with date they ordered, and i need get from two rows [12][13] echo each single echo row. from latest to oldest from 2 rows in one variable

[image mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYDjU.png) -> i need from this two rows get **TOP LIST from the latest(newest) to the oldest**

```
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY publishedAt DESC, publishedAt1 DESC";
$i = 0;
    if ($latest=mysqli_query($conn,$sqll)) {
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($latest)){  
            $allchannels[] = $row[12];
            echo $allchannels[$i++].' / ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add an example of what you want your result to look like in your post.

Comment: Now i just get all data from one row, i need get all data from two rows in one variable. but single rows. i think need merge two rows i don't know to do that.

Comment: Please improve your question to explain what your database table data looks like and your exact desired output.  You are going to keep receiving **low-quality "guesses"** while your question is Unclear.  You shouldn't be using `*` in your SELECT if you know what you need to access.

Comment: We can easily do this for you...  But I have asked three times now for an example of what you want your data to look like.  Please post an example of your expected output in your question.

Comment: updated question

Comment: Why is `12` magical?  What named columns are your trying to access?  How should the result set be structured?  How are you displaying to screen?  What is `/` for?  Are you merely asking for: `SELECT publishedAt, publishedAt1 FROM users ORDER BY publishedAt DESC, publishedAt1 DESC`?  Then you could access column indexes `[0]` and `[1]` in each row. I don't know what you are doing.

Comment: cuz i have 17 rows in 12[publishedAt] and 13[publishedAt1] thats all

Comment: How are you printing this data to screen?  What are you doing with the result set?  Are you filling an html table?

Comment: Mickmackusa watch the code. i getting results from echo $allchannels[$i++]; but i getting result only from one column publishedAt i need get from two columns publishedAt and publishedAt1 -> echo $allchannels[$i++];

Comment: You are not re-declaring `$i` on each iteration, so you aren't dealing with `0` and `1`.  You are dealing with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.  What is the slash for?  What is your desired output?  Do you want to reformat the datetime? I cannot post an answer while your question is Unclear.

Comment: slash / to see the separation it's like <br /> like i said i need get from two columns publishedAt publishedAt1 into one variable. then i can get from two columns [12][13] one ordered TOP LIST from newest to oldest. now only from one column working. i need from one to two but in one variable.

Comment: $allchannels[] = $row[12] . ' ' . $row[13]; like this but into single columns, with this i get two colums in one echo.

Comment: enabling error reporting and applying `mysqli_error($conn)` to the query produced what, if any errors? @KietasBicas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to increment a counter to access the two columns of data in each row.
Don't ask for more in your resultset than you intend to use.

```
$sqll = "SELECT publishedAt, publishedAt1 FROM users";
if ($latest = mysqli_query($conn,$sqll)) {
    $datetimes = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($latest)){
        $datetimes[] = $row[0];
        $datetimes[] = $row[1];
    }
    rsort($datetimes);  // descending order
    echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr><td>" , implode("</td></tr><tr><td>", $datetimes) , "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

This will only return the two desired columns of data for each row.

The output will be:

```
|--------------------------|
| 2018-09-10T13:41:14.000Z |
| 2018-09-09T10:00:05.000Z |
| 2018-09-07T11:10:54.000Z |
| 2018-09-04T12:00:03.000Z |
| ... etc ...              |
|--------------------------|
```

---

More simply you could use a UNION to create one column of datetimes and ORDER BY to sort the result set.

```
SELECT publishedAt AS stamp FROM `users` UNION SELECT publishedAt1 AS stamp FROM publishedAt1 ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

Then just iterated the sorted column data like this:

```
echo "<table border=1>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($latest)){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it's working like $allchannels[ $row[12] ] = $row[13]; i need in single... TWO columns -> one $variable -> echo $variable result from two columns like TOP LIST 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. not 1. 1. 2. 2.

Comment: Yes that what i need ! but now have bad order what you can offer? to precisely sorted?

Comment: order by date from two colums cuz now works not currently short https://i.gyazo.com/d902a07a20d9e07c74e24de23547441b.png now works good but just need precisely ranked newest 1 place oldest latest place 1. newest 2. older 3. older then 2 and more..

Comment: Yes !!  i want all of the date time marget in single array and then sort them all from newest to oldest.

Comment: Great.  Then while you are here, let's "fix up" your question.  Please provide your two columns of data as copy-pasted text (instead of an image).  Once you add that bit, I can help to edit the question and better describe your desired output.  It's okay to be new -- we all started somewhere.  For this site to stay valuable, we must all care to keep the content clean and readable.

Comment: Okey, sorry im there new

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly you can try this:

```
$allchannels[] = $row[12] . ' ' . $row[13];
```

OR:

```
$allchannels[] = array(

  $row[12],
  $row[13]

);
```

OR:

```
$allchannels[] = $row[12];
$allchannels[] = $row[13];
```

Comment: Edited question, almost but i need each echo row to be single.

Comment: You need to post an example of what you expect your output to look like.

Comment: Try this (code-only) answers are low-value on StackOverflow. Please edit your answer to include some explanation about how your solution works and why it is a good idea. (even simple solutions should endeavor to educate the OP and future researchers)

Comment: @mickmackusa I would if I could figure out what he wants.

Comment: That's why you should never answer Unclear questions.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you could make this way:

```
$allchannels[ $row[12] ] = $row[13];
```

This way one would be the index and the other the value, making it single.

Comment: then i get this error Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in -> echo $allchannels[$i++];

Comment: That's because `$i` will run all the way up to 16 with your 17 rows of data.